# C# Unable to update the text using itext sharp

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, itext

As per my previous post [ITextsharp to edit existing pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559507/itextsharp-to-edit-existing-pdf/39559738?noredirect=1#comment66458215_39559738) I am able to save the PDF in interactive manner. After that I started writing the following code to modify the content and save it to a PDF as follow but when I am trying to open the file it is saying `There was an error opening in the document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired`

This is my code

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"E:\\Test.pdf");
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream, '\0', true);
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    AcroFields af = reader.AcroFields;
    string[] fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields.Fields.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
    for (int key = 0; key <= fields.Count() - 1; key++)
    {
      pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(fields[key], txtApplicantName.Text);
    }
    Byte[] bytes= memoryStream.ToArray();
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\\Test1.pdf", bytes);
}
```

Can some one tell me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close the `PdfStamper`.

```
pdfStamper.Close(); // <===
Byte[] bytes= memoryStream.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\\Test1.pdf", bytes);
```